# How to get all the textboxes linked to a corresponding select field?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Basically, I want to make a site with a button that repeatedly asks user for input. However, one of the inputs that the site asks for involves a select field and depending on the select field, have a corresponding text field appear or dissapear(values none). My javascript utilizes a for loop as the user can repeatedly press the button to add more and more select fields( and corresponding text field).

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tm6738qb/66/)

Below is the example code of what I'm trying to do.

HTML

```
    <div><select class="DISPLAYTYPE" id="QBox" data-fieldtype="P">
                    <option value = "text">TextBox</option>
                    <option value = "check">CheckBox</option>
                    <option value = "radio">Radio</option>
                </select></div>

      <input type="number" min="1" value="LENGTH" class="quantumBox" id="P">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    var textBoxList = document.getElementsByClassName("DISPLAYTYPE");
         for (var i=0; i<textBoxList.length;i++){
    textBoxList[i].addEventListener('change', function(){

     var subParam = textBoxList[i].options[textBoxList.selectedIndex].value;

     if(subParam ="text"){
        //make ONLY corresponding input box appear
     }else{
     //make ONLY corresponding input box dissapear
     }

  })

 };
```

EDIT: This is the Structure

```
[table id="rootPlacement"]

//insert here

[/table]

[button/] <--This will make a duplicate of invisible html and place it under invisible root 



//The invisible html stuff we want to duplicate into //insert here
```

Comment: what is the actual structure of the select and input fields layout, the hierarchy can you add actual code that is generated, does all three types specified in the select dropdown will be very next to the select drop-down as in above and not anywhere else ?

Comment: please add how all three inputs type will be in the html structure, which are needed to be shown on selection of the option

Comment: This is the javascript that will duplicate and create more of these forms: https://pastebin.com/E0rJChb6.  Essentially I will make this "QBox" invisible to the user. Whenver they click the button, this js code runs and duplicates it and also will later update the id so we later have "QBox1" and "QBox2" etc...

Comment: ok but how would i know where `.rootPlacement` element is used in the HTML ? and initially all these 3 inputs will be hidden ?

Comment: Did an edit that showed where the .rootPlacement element will be used in the HTML. And yes these 3 inputs will initially be hidden. The input should only happen if the user clicks the button

Comment: is this html structure correct ? https://pastebin.com/KAdhZU5k

Comment: Yeah! Thats is basically exactly what I had in mind!

Comment: do mark the answer as correct if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Given your feedback about the HTML structure in the comments, you can use the following to achieve what you are trying to. Just look into

- You are trying to get the selected value inside the `change` event for the drop-down by using `var subParam = textBoxList[i].options[textBoxList.selectedIndex].value;` rather than using `textBoxList[i]` you can use `this` so that i becomes `var subParam = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value`.
- For showing hiding the inputs you can use the `function findRoot()` which takes the target element object i.e ``select`and finds a parent with the class named`rootPlacement` and returns the node and then you can iterate it's children to show the selected node and hide the rest.

See a demo below

```js
var textBoxList = document.querySelectorAll(".DISPLAYTYPE");


for (var i = 0; i < textBoxList.length; i++) {
  textBoxList[i].addEventListener('change', function() {

    var selectedType = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    let rootPlacement = findRoot(this, 'rootPlacement');
    let children = rootPlacement.children;

    for (var c = 0; c < children.length; c++) {
      let element = children[c];
      let elementType = element.type;
      let isInputElement = typeof elementType !== 'undefined';

      if (isInputElement) {
        if (elementType == selectedType) {
          element.style.display = 'inline';
        } else {
          element.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    }
  });

};

function findRoot(el, cls) {
  while ((el = el.parentElement) && !el.classList.contains(cls));
  return el;
}
```

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="rootPlacement">
  <div>
    <select class="DISPLAYTYPE" id="QBox1" data-fieldtype="P">
      <option value="text">TextBox</option>
      <option value="checkbox">CheckBox</option>
      <option value="radio">Radio</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <input type="text" value="" class="quantumBox" id="P1">
  <input type="checkbox" value="" class="quantumBox" id="q1">
  <input type="radio" value="" class="quantumBox" id="r1">
</div>
<div class="rootPlacement">
  <div>
    <select class="DISPLAYTYPE" id="QBox2" data-fieldtype="P">
      <option value="text">TextBox</option>
      <option value="checkbox">CheckBox</option>
      <option value="radio">Radio</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <input type="text" value="LENGTH" class="quantumBox" id="P2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="" class="quantumBox" id="q2">
  <input type="radio" value="LENGTH" class="quantumBox" id="r2">
</div>
<div class="rootPlacement">
  <div>
    <select class="DISPLAYTYPE" id="QBox3" data-fieldtype="P">
      <option value="text">TextBox</option>
      <option value="checkbox">CheckBox</option>
      <option value="radio">Radio</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <input type="text" value="LENGTH" class="quantumBox" id="P3">
  <input type="checkbox" value="" class="quantumBox" id="q3">
  <input type="radio" value="LENGTH" class="quantumBox" id="r3">

</div>
```